# ("Divorced", "get a divorce", "get divorced") + from (each other / one another)

Tags: word-usage, sentence-construction, difference

I was wondering which one of the choices below sounds natural when they are followed by "from each other" or "from one another":

1. > David’s parents **divorced** from each other when he was six.
2. > David’s parents **got a divorce** from each other when he was six.
3. > David’s parents **got divorced** from each other when he was six.

I have no idea whether **normally** people use "from each other" or "from one another" after "divorce" in English.

I think they all should be correct and see nothing wrong with them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All three are correct; however I would not say "divorced from each other" because it's redundant.  A "divorce" is, by definition, from one's spouse, so

> David's parents **divorced** when he was six.

This actually applies to your other two examples:

> David's parents **got a divorce** when he was six.
>
> David's parents **got divorced** when he was six.

The only time "from each other" is useful is when there is some ambiguity who divorced who.

> In an unusual twist, David's parents actually **were divorced** from each other when he was born.

If you were to just say "were divorced" in this sentence, without explanation, it implies *from other people*.